# Java : How can convert String to HttpInputMessage

Tags: java, string, httpresponse

How can I convert String to HttpInputMessage?
or HttpResponse to HttpInputMessage

Post (return json):

```
HttpResponse<String> jsonResponse = null;
try {
    jsonResponse = Unirest.post(targetURL).header("Accept", "application/json")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json;").body(urlParameters).asString();
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String str = jsonResponse.toString();
HttpInputMessage inputMessage = null;

return inputMessage;
```

I want convert json to Object

```
RoutesList routes = new RoutesList();
Post post = new Post(this.url + allRoutes, depoId.toString());
HttpInputMessage inputMessage = null;
try {
    inputMessage = post.getResult();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    converter.read(routes.getClass(), RoutesList.class, inputMessage);
} catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the HttpResponse using this class HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse:

```
HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse)
```

And return it as HttpInputMessag, for example:

```
return new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse(jsonResponse)
```

this class implement the interface HttpInputMessage.

Comment: The type HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse is not visible

Comment: should be: `org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse`

Comment: It say "The type org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpResponse is not visible"